# Connecting to SQL Server in Windows 2019 Datacenter

Tags: odbc

A script I'm trying to run requires that I specify an ODBC driver in the connection string to access a SQL Server database. However I am unable to install an ODBC driver on the OS I'm using which is a Windows 2019 Datacenter.

Just wondering if there are any drivers that support this OS as I couldn't find anything online and how would I go about this.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you already have the ODBC driver installed in your OS:
Control Panel -> System and Security -> Administrative Tools -> ODBC Data Sources -> Drivers tab

If you do not see an ODBC driver in the list, install the new SQL Server Management Studio 18 and you should see an ODBC Driver also installed.

[image]

Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/odbc/dn170514(v=vs.85)

Comment: I've come across this issue recently and I realized that I already have an ODBC Driver 17 in my Windows 2019 Datacenter edition. It could be that either the OS already comes with an ODBC Driver installed or I got it as an add-on with my SQL Server Management Studio 18 installation.